# Place a css class in a div using MVC and Razor

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have used following code to add css class:

```
<div id="123" class="tab-pane @{ if (some_condition) { Html.Raw("active"); }; } ">
```

But it did not work.

I hope for this result:

```
<div id="123" class="tab-pane active">
```

Comment: Just a note.  If you know the condition, why not handle this in the controller and return the proper value in the Model for the View.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@MichaelPerrenoud's answer is close.  You need to wrap the whole conditional in parenthesis.

Using @() tells razor to output a string. So

```
<div id="123" class='tab-pane @(condition ? "active" : "")'>
```

Comment: No need for single-quotes. regular double-quotes will do.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be wanting to do this:

```
<div id="123" class='tab-pane @some_condition ? "active" : ""'>
```

Comment: @user3112333, if this fixed it for you please consider up voting and marking it as the answer. I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Comment: Thank you, but this way you suggested did not work. Do you know any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can add javascript code

```
    <script>
       @if(true)
       $('#123').addClass("active");
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you! So will works! But I would not use javascript at the moment. Do you know any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
<div id="123" class="tab-pane @if (some_condition) { <text>active</text>  }">
```